# Sidekiq: error handler threw an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I keep getting this error (without any backtrace) in my production logs:

```
!!! ERROR HANDLER THREW AN ERROR !!!
```

For my understanding that means that a [registered error handler](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling) is raising an exception.

However my application doesn't have any custom error handler.

How can I debug / solve this issue?

---

My application looks like this:

```
class DeliveryJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: :deliveries, retry: 3

  sidekiq_retry_in { |count| 20 * (3 ** count) }

  sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |s|
    # do something (some methods use Redis) ...
    Rails.logger.tagged('delivery') do 
      Rails.logger.error "Sidekiq retries exhausted for ..."
    end
  end

  def perform(id)
    Notification.find(id).deliver
  end
end

class Notification
  def deliver
    # do something that may fail
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.tagged('delivery') do 
      Rails.logger.error "Delivery error for #{endpoint}: #{e.to_s}"
    end
    raise e
  end
end
```

So in my logs I often see something like:

> Delivery error for https://example.com/path: SSL connection error, etc.

Followed by:

```
!!! ERROR HANDLER THREW AN ERROR !!!
```

The `Delivery error` is ok and expected, however I don't understand why I get an error from an error handler.

Comment: The `!!! ERROR HANDLER THREW AN ERROR !!!` is probably caused by the fact that I `rescue` from exceptions in a method, I log the error and I raise the exception again. I don't know why Sidekiq complains.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/d8f11c26518dbe967880f76fd23bb99e9d2411d5/lib/sidekiq/exception_handler.rb#L23

Sidekiq throws this error from its own error handler.

Comment: Yes, I've seen those lines. However I don't have any custom error handler: why Sidekiq says that there's an error handler that raises an exception? Moreover, why I don't get any backtrace? **I don't even get the exception name!** I mean, line 24, should log the exception name, but it doesn't. I just get `!!! ERROR HANDLER THREW AN ERROR !!!` without any additional information.